# Azure Key Vault 401 authentication errors

Tags: dependencies, azure-application-insights, http-status-code-401, azure-keyvault

I am fetching secret values from key vault for my azure stateless service fabric application and getting  401 dependency errors (if I check via connected application insight) for only 2 key vault secrets out of 100s key vault secrets.
Below given is the screenshot of dependency error shown via application insight for one of the key vault secret.

[image]

Here request path is https://mykeyvaultname.vault.azure.net:443/secrets/PushMessagingSecretsTopicName/?api-version=7.0

My code to fetch the key vault secret is given below-

```
    public async Task<string> GetSecretAsync(string secretName, string clientId, string appKey, string vaultAddress)
            {
                string secretValue = string.Empty;
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(secretName))
                    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(secretName));

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(clientId))
                    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(clientId));

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(appKey))
                    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(appKey));

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(vaultAddress))
                    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(vaultAddress));

                var secretIdentifier = vaultAddress + "secrets/" + secretName;
                string cacheKey = secretIdentifier + clientId + appKey;

                secretValue = await GetSecretValue(clientId, appKey, secretIdentifier, cacheKey);

                return secretValue;
            }

private async Task<string> GetSecretValue(string clientId, string appKey, string secretIdentifier, string cacheKey)
        {
            IAdAuthentication authToken = new AdAuthentication
            {
                ClientId = clientId,
                AppKey = appKey
            };
            KeyVaultClient keyVaultClient = new KeyVaultClient(authToken.GetAuthenticationTokenAsync);

            // Get secret from the KeyVault.

            SecretBundle secret = null;

            Task tskGetSecret = Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                        //Here I am getting exception with response
                        secret = await keyVaultClient.GetSecretAsync(secretIdentifier).ConfigureAwait(false);
            });
            await Task.WhenAny(tskGetSecret);

            if (tskGetSecret.IsFaulted || tskGetSecret.IsCanceled)
            {
                secret = null;
            }

            string secretValue = string.Empty;
            if (secret != null && secret.Value != null)
            {
                secretValue = secret.Value.Trim();
            }

            return secretValue;
        }
```

I have debugged the issue further and below given is my finding-

1. Exception occurs at the time of fetching value of specific keyVaultSecret.
2. Along with exception, value of secret is also being fetched successfully.
3. Exception is:`Microsoft.Rest.TransientFaultHandling.HttpRequestWithStatusException: 'Response status code indicates server error: 401 (Unauthorized).'`

StackTrace:-

```
at Microsoft.Rest.RetryDelegatingHandler.<>c__DisplayClass11_0.<<SendAsync>b__1>d.MoveNext()
```

Answer (score 1):

I am closing this issue as with further debugging I found that issue is not intermittent and not related to specific key vault secrets. Issue always occurs while fetching value of first key vault secret for the application. I am closing this issue and opened a [new issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52963144/exception-while-fetching-value-of-first-key-vault-secret-for-the-application) with proper details.